# Ionic Maps markers won't show

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing an Ionic project based on Google Maps Javascript SDK.

It seems to kind of work but my markers (and circle) won't show on map. I looked all over Google and SO for answers but I cannot help it.

Just for the record, the code is copied from an AngularJS project. It all worked well, no errors at all, every marker, circle and infoWindow worked properly.

Please help me, here's my code.

```js
import { identifierModuleUrl } from '@angular/compiler/compiler';
import { Component, NgZone, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ActionSheetController, AlertController, App, LoadingController, NavController, Platform, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 GoogleMapOptions,
 CameraPosition,
 MarkerOptions,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

//declare var google: any

@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html',
})

export class MapPage {

  map: GoogleMap;
  constructor(private googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    const hotspots = [
        {
            "id":           1,
            "lat":          45,
            "long":         25,
            "year":         2017,
            "month":        10,
            "day":          7,
            "startHour":    20,
            "startMinutes": 15,
            "endHour":      21,
            "endMinutes":   20,
            "probability":  100,
            "description":  "asdasdasdf"
        },
        {
            "id":           2,
            "lat":          46,
            "long":         26,
            "year":         2017,
            "month":        10,
            "day":          7,
            "startHour":    20,
            "startMinutes": 15,
            "endHour":      21,
            "endMinutes":   20,
            "probability":  100
        }
    ];

    const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    let markers: Array<Object> = [];
    let unauthorizedMarkers: Array<Object> = [];
    let addHotspotListener: boolean = false;
    let addHotspotClass: boolean = false;
    let infoWindowHover: boolean = false;
    const mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
        zoom:      5,
        center:    new google.maps.LatLng(44.32, 23.8),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    const Circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor:   'black',
        strokeOpacity: 0.08,
        strokeWeight:  20,
        fillColor:     '#add8e6',
        fillOpacity:   0.40,
        setMap:           map,
        radius:        100000,
        visible:       true,
        flag:          false
    });

    function addHotspot() {
        addHotspotListener = true;
        addHotspotClass    = true;

        if (Circle.visible === true) {
            Circle.setVisible(false);
            Circle.flag = true;
        }
        markers.forEach( (marker) => {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        });
    };

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function (e) {

        console.log("click listener 1");
        let myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(e.latLng.lat()), parseFloat(e.latLng.lng()));

        infoWindow.close();
        infoWindowHover = false;

        if (addHotspotListener) {
            let info          = {};
            const today       = new Date();
            info.year         = today.getFullYear();
            info.month        = today.getMonth();
            info.day          = today.getDate();
            info.startHour    = today.getHours();
            info.startMinutes = today.getMinutes();

            createMarker(myLatLng, 'unauth');

            addHotspotClass = false;
            addHotspotListener = false;

            if (Circle.flag === true) {
                Circle.setVisible(true);
                Circle.flag = false;
                markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                    if (Circle.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else marker.setVisible(false);
                });
            }
            return;
        }
        Circle.setCenter(myLatLng);
        console.log("circle", myLatLng);
        Circle.setVisible(true);

        markers.forEach(function (marker) {
            if (Circle.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else marker.setVisible(false);
        });
    });

    function createMarker (info, type) {
        let myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long);
        console.log(myLatLng);
        let icon   = {
            url:        'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/hex/512/warning-icon.png',
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
        };
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            setMap:      map,
            position: myLatLng,
            icon:     icon,
            title:    '',
            visible:  true,
            content:  '<p>info</p>'
        });

        if (type === 'default') {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(marker.content);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        else if (type === 'unauth') {
            icon.url = 'https://png.icons8.com/ask-question/color/1600';
            marker.setIcon(icon);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent('<p>info</p>');
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            infoWindow.setContent('<p>info</p>');
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            setTimeout(function () {
                infoWindow.close();
            }, 3000);
            unauthorizedMarkers.push(marker);
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
          if(!infoWindowHover)
            infoWindow.close();

          infoWindowHover = false;
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            compute.increase(marker);
            hotspots = compute.get();
            load();

            infoWindowHover = true;
        });
    };


    // LOAD MARKERS
    function load() {
      hotspots.forEach(function (marker) {
          console.log(marker.lat, marker.long);
          createMarker(marker, 'default');
      });
    };

    load();
  }
}
```

Comment: you are only calling `load()` in the in the `click` handler...is that right?

Comment: no sir, it is inside loadMap() which is called on ionViewDidLoad(). It runs as it console.logs me everywhere. thank you for your answer!